# How can I add loopback adapters with the command line and configure them with the command line?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, batch, loopback

What is the command line to add a loopback adapter with IP 127.0.0.2 on Windows 8.1?

I need to add 65,000 ip's to my local machine for network stress tests (connections from many different IP's) for an application.

Comment: look [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=windows+add+loopback+adapter+command+line)

Comment: You do *assume* I did not search before asking... if the search is that useful - please go ahead and tell me the command

Comment: Sorry. Then it may be helpfull to know what you tried from the solutions and what didn't work.

Comment: well I don't know anything else to try to allocate a 65K block on a windows machine, on linux it's easy but I have to do it with Windows now.

Comment: `devcon -r install %WINDIR%\Inf\Netloop.inf *MSLOOP` by [this source](http://ss64.com/nt/devcon.html) and [installing Devcon](http://joequery.me/guides/windows-8-toggle-touch-screen/#installing-devcon)